# Application and blog on the same server and domain

Tags: wordpress, symfony, nginx, server-configuration

I want to deploy my Symfony application on some server with domain example.com.
Besides I want to use another standalone Wordpress blog in my Symfony application and set that example.com/blog  goes to WordPress blog.
My server is under nginx and I am not quite good in server configuration, so could you advice me the solution how to cope with it? Is this good idea to hold those apps under same domain?

I have tried to search some solution in internet but got some results for Apache2 - which is not my case.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) then check it against your own configuration, usually in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`